# UWP - Cannot delete file - File lock

Tags: c#, file, uwp, async-await, storage

I had a problem with 'RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync()' which couldn't download some files because of some Firewall problems (as I assume). I had to find a solution to cancel the download and I came up with this.

```
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);
            }).Wait(cancelDownload.Token);
        });
        inputStream.Dispose();
        outputStream.Dispose();
```

When a download is with faults the file has to be deleted. This is what I use:

```
    async public Task DeleteFileAsync(string filename)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = await App.GetDocumentFolder();
        try
        {
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            await file.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.Warn(e.Message)
        }
    }
```

Now what's weird is that the file is not deleted. At the same time my Code doesn't jump into the 'catch' part.

BUT the file gets deleted AFTER closing the UWP application.

I assume that 'await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream);' locks the file so I cannot delete it?!

Are there any possibilities to remove that file lock? Maybe I need something other than '.Dispose()' ?

Comment: Please call `CopyAndCloseAsync` as task and give it a token like  `await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(inputStream, outputStream).AsTask(cancelDownload.Token);`

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Tried it. I created a byteobserver for that file. The file stays at 0 bytes. My CancelDownload.Token get cancelled but my UWP application is stuck at 'await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync()' till the download is finished (which will never be)

Comment: Why you wrap double task for `CopyAndCloseAsync ` method?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT The async Task is needed so I can cancel the stuck-download and continue to download the next file. The sync Task is needed so my UI doesn't freeze

Comment: Could you mind share a sample for us, I will test and edit base on your demo.